# Enterprise Architect - How can I specify a computed column in a database model?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am trying to specify a computed column in a data model built with Enterprise Architect 9.3.  The object model (per the API docs) certainly has a place holder (IsDerived) for computed attributes, and it is possible to enter check constraints with code snippets.

Is it possible to model a computed column through the data modelling tool in EA and specify the computation as you can specify the code of a check constraint?  If so how?